# Read installed rpm packages from damaged installation

Tags: fedora, rpm

The SSD of my notebook gave up and the fedora 36 system is not bootable any more. Although the home partition is fully backupped, I have no recent list of installed packages.
The root partition is still readable from a live system and I would like to know if it's possible to somehow access the rpmdb and extract a list of installed packages.
This would make it much easier to reinstall the system on a new SSD.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1471934/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-installed-centos-packages-by-only-reading-from-the-files seems to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rpm -qa --dbpath /mnt/somewhere/usr/lib/sysimage/rpm | sort`